# How to mock the Context based on an interface when using Ninject?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq, ninject

I have my normal Entity Framework context, which is like this:

```
public class LikvidoWebsitesApiContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext
{   
   // code
}
```

I have made an interface, which has my `DBSets`.

In my normal solution, I set it up in *Ninject* like this:

```
kernel.Bind<ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext>().To<LikvidoWebsitesApiContext>().InRequestScope();
```

I use the context in my services by adding the `ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext` inside the constructor, and then I can use the database.

**My question is: how do I set this up in the unit Test?**

I have tried to do the following:

```
kernel.Bind(typeof(ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext))
            .To(typeof(Mock<LikvidoWebsitesApiContext>))
            .Register(true);
```

(Using the `Moq` framework)

However, this gives the:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Moq.Mock`1[Likvido.Domain.Services.Data.LikvidoWebsitesApiContext]' to type 'Likvido.Domain.Services.Data.ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext'.'

Which do make sense, but I am very unsure how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a quick look at the Ninject wiki I came across

[Providers, Factory Methods and the Activation Context](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Providers%2C-Factory-Methods-and-the-Activation-Context)

Where they show how to use a `Provider` to build up instances.

Following the suggestion in the wiki it was advised to extend `Provider<T>` which includes strong typing.

```
public MoqContextProvider : Provider<ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext> {
    protected override ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext CreateInstance(IContext context) {
        var mock = new Mock<ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext>();

        // Set up of mock members

        return mock.Object;
    }
}
```

And then it is just a matter of plugging into the container

```
kernel.Bind<ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext>().ToProvider(new MoqContextProvider());
```

There was also a suggestion about using *Factory Methods*

> A lighter weight alternative to writing `IProvider` implementations is to bind a service to a delegate method.

```
kernal.Bind<ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext>()
    .ToMethod(context => {
        var mock = new Mock<ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext>();

        // Set up of mock members

        return mock.Object;    
    });
```

The provided `Func` will be bound to the service type for deferred binding and called later when a new instance of the service (i.e. `ILikvidoWebsitesApiContext`) is required.

Remember that when using Moq you need to set up the desired behavior of the mocks.